# Trying to open an "Excluded from Project" View in VS2015 throws exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, exception, model-view-controller

I've been trying to solve this problem for some time now, but with no avail :(
This happens when I try to open an excluded view (has to be excluded for the app to run) which throws me this error:

> An exception has been encountered. This may have be caused by an extension. You can get more information...

Extract from ActivityLog.xml

```
<entry>
    <record>711</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.089</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>712</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.089</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>713</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.089</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>714</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.089</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>715</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.089</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>716</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.089</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>717</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.090</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>718</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.090</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>719</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.090</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>720</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>721</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>722</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>723</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>724</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>725</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>726</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>727</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.092</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>728</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.092</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>729</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.092</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>730</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.092</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>731</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.092</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>732</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.092</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>733</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.092</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>734</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.092</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>735</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.093</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>736</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.093</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>737</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.093</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>738</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.093</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>739</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.093</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>740</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.093</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>741</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.093</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>742</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.095</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>743</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.095</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>744</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.095</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>745</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.095</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>746</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.095</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>747</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.095</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>748</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.096</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>749</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.096</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>750</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.097</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>751</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.097</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>752</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.097</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>753</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.097</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>754</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.097</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>755</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.097</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>756</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.097</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>757</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.097</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>758</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.098</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>759</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.098</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>760</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.098</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>761</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.098</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>762</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.098</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>763</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.098</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>764</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.099</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>765</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.099</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>766</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.099</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>767</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.099</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>768</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.099</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>769</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.099</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>770</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.099</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>771</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.099</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>772</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.100</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>773</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.100</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>774</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.100</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>775</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.100</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Advertised (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>776</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.100</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing AssemblyFolders (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>777</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.100</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Fusion (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>778</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.100</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGen (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>779</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.100</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing NGenQueue (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>780</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.101</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing policy (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>781</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.101</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Security (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>782</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.101</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Microsoft.VisualStudio.IDE.ToolboxControlsInstaller.ToolboxInstallerPackage</source>
    <description>Exception parsing Windows Presentation Foundation (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework) as a version</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>783</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:03.139</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Done loading new toolbox content, total time = 281 ms</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>784</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:04.944</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Entering function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>785</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:04.944</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Leaving function VBDispatch::GetTypeLib</description>
    <guid>{80CC9F66-E7D8-4DDD-85B6-D9E6CD0E93E2}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>786</record>
    <time>2016/06/22 11:00:24.593</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.&#x000D;&#x000A;Parameter name: key&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Extensions.ExtensionsManager.OnTextViewCreated(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Controller.TextViewConnectionListener.OnTextViewGotAggregateFocus(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Commands.Html.VsHtmlTextViewConnectionListener.OnTextViewGotAggregateFocus(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer textBuffer)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Controller.TextViewConnectionListener.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass24_0.&lt;OnTextViewConnected&gt;b__0(Object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent(Object sender, EventHandler eventHandlers)</description>
  </entry>
```

Comment: Additional Notes: This also happens when I try to merge two documents together (doesn't matter whether its a controller/model/view). I have tried a clean install and for some time - it works but soon again, happens again.

Comment: Fixed it for now: Cleared VS Cache and Installed latest updated - also Cleaned and Re-built the solution. In addition to this - I have removed some Extensions which I don't know what they were doing there e.g. Glyphfriend.

Comment: What do you mean by VS Cache? I'm facing the same problem, but deleting my .suo file and a clean build didn't help.

Comment: Cleaning the VS Cache pretty much means resetting Visual Studio. I followed this guide: https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know of that beast ;-)